# What to make of differeing results from standardized means and density when balancing a data set?

Tags: causality, propensity-scores, matching

I am attempting to estimate the effect of a treatment (`pko`) on a specific outcome and I am using IPW to do so, along with nearest neighbor matching and coarsened exact matching for robustness purposes. When assessing how well each strategy balanced the data set, I've come across seemingly contradictory findings using two different metrics: distributional balance and the absolute standardized difference in means.

When looking at the Absolute SMD, IPW seems to balance the data set very well compared to NN matching and CEM. However, when I assess distributional balance via density plots, it actually appears that the NN matching and CEM do better at balancing the treated and non-treated distribution. This is a bit puzzling to me and I am wondering if anyone has an idea of why IPW may seem to balance better when looking at SMD, but the matching methods seem to balance better when examined via distributional balance. I'll attach some balancing graphics for reference.

[image]

[image]

While this density plot reflects one of many covariates, this one alone is a good illustrative example of my inquiry (and its easier to show one rather than all). The common theme is that CEM preforms best.

Comment: Which variable in the love plot does `lnatres` refer to? This kind of thing can happen. SMDs are not a good balance statistic to use to decide if a sample is better balanced because it misses other features of the covariate distribution. Note that because CEM drops treated units it doesn't target the same estimand as the other two.

Comment: @Noah `lnatres` refers to the "Natural Resources pc" variable. Also, I am a bit confused on your comments on CEM. My CEM sample does include treated units. Maybe I am misunderstanding you?

Comment: The density plot for CEM indicates that some treated units were dropped. You can verify this by using `bal.tab()` on the object resulting from the matching.